# improve read spead simple db boto

Tags: python, amazon-simpledb, boto

I have a script that reads simpledb domains and writes them to s3. the performance is mediocre at best.  Is there a way to increase the read speed?

```
import boto
import datetime
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
from boto.s3.key import Key

awsa = "myawsaccesskey"
awss = "myawssecretkey"

conn = boto.connect_sdb(awsa, awss)
domains = conn.get_all_domains()
s3conn = boto.connect_s3(awsa, awss)
archbucket = s3conn.get_bucket("simpledbbu")
for d in domains:
    print d.name
    doc = None
    doc = Document()
    root = doc.createElement("items")
    doc.appendChild(root)
    countermax = 0
    counter = 0
    for item in d:
        print "loading {0} of {1}".format(counter,countermax)
        counter += 1
        node = doc.createElement("item")
        node.setAttribute("itemName", item.name)
        for k,v in item.items():
            if not isinstance(v, basestring):
                i = 0
                for val in v:
                    node.setAttribute("{0}::{1}".format(k,i),val)
                    i += 1
            else:
                node.setAttribute(k,v)
        root.appendChild(node)
    k = Key(archbucket)
    k.key = "{0}/{1}".format(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"),d.name)
    x = doc.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
    k.set_contents_from_string(x)
```

here's the profile:

```
ncalls  tottime percall cumtime percall filename:lineno(function)
2035    1.312   0.001   1.312   0.001   {built-in method read}
2   0.445   0.223   0.445   0.223   {built-in method do_handshake}
17  0.355   0.021   0.355   0.021   {built-in method write}
2   0.321   0.161   0.321   0.161   {_ssl.sslwrap}
2   0.292   0.146   0.292   0.146   {_socket.getaddrinfo}
2   0.177   0.089   0.177   0.089   {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}
14  0.012   0.001   0.077   0.005   {built-in method Parse}
2   0.01    0.005   0.047   0.023   __init__.py:24(<module>)
3369    0.01    0   0.012   0   item.py:71(endElement)
1   0.009   0.009   3.185   3.185   backupSimpleDb_0.0.py:1(<module>)
3508    0.009   0   0.03    0   expatreader.py:300(start_element)
4145    0.008   0   0.011   0   StringIO.py:208(write)
3508    0.007   0   0.019   0   handler.py:31(startElement)
3508    0.007   0   0.02    0   handler.py:37(endElement)
1   0.006   0.006   0.006   0.006   {nt.urandom}
3114    0.006   0   0.009   0   item.py:58(startElement)
1208    0.005   0   0.005   0   minidom.py:343(__init__)
1208    0.005   0   0.025   0   minidom.py:686(setAttribute)
258/3   0.005   0   0.024   0.008   minidom.py:794(writexml)
1   0.004   0.004   0.007   0.007   exception.py:26(<module>)
1   0.004   0.004   0.007   0.007   expatreader.py:4(<module>)
1   0.004   0.004   0.007   0.007   urllib.py:23(<module>)
1   0.004   0.004   0.006   0.006   utils.py:5(<module>)
```

Comment: It's better to run the profiler yourself, and include the results of profiling.  If the big time delay is outside your code, then there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run 5 or 10 threads in parallel and have each copy one domain.

This is actually pretty simple if you use a queue for domains to copy and have the threads wait for elements in the queue.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer but if you're just looking to backup your simpledb domains on s3, I've had decent performance with boto's [to_xml()](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/ref/sdb.html#boto.sdb.domain.Domain.to_xml) function.  Plus, you don't need to roll your own simpledb parser.

Comment: that's fine when you have a small domain.  You will crash your memory trying that on a large domain...